# Create a .exe.config file from C# code

Tags: c#, .net

I look for a method to directly create my .exe.config file from my C # code without creating it manually.

I searched but I only found methods to read or write

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: What else were you expecting other than reading and writing?

Comment: how i can create .exe.config file from my code C#

Comment: So you want your application to be able to write to its own directory? What a great security breach ;)